# Sum of integer Division matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

Here is a question from previous HackerEarth Challenge -

Roy has a matrix of size NxN. Rows and Columns are numbered from 1 to N.
jth column of ith row contains integer division i/j.

In other words, Matrix[i][j] = int(i/j) where 1 ≤ i, j ≤ N.

```
Your task is to find sum of this matrix i.e.

sum = 0
for i=1 to N-1
    for j=1 to N-1
        sum += Matrix[i][j]
Constraints:
1 ≤ T ≤ 10
1 ≤ N ≤ 1000000
```

and here is my solution to this problem

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;
#define MAXT 10
#define MAXN 1000000
long long solve(long long N){
    long long ans = 0;
    for(int i=1;i<N-1;i++)
    {
    for(int j=1; j<N-1 ; j++)
    {
        int temp = N*i/j;
        ans = ans + temp;
    }
    }
    return ans;
}
int main(){
    int T, N;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    assert(T>0 and T<=MAXT);
    while(T--){
        scanf("%d", &N);
        assert(N>0 and N<=MAXN);
        printf("%lld\n", solve((long long)N));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the output of this program is not coming correct.

So please tell me if I have achieved things here correctly. 
If yes what else can I do to optimize this code. Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't `int temp = N*i/j;` be `int temp = i/j;`?

Comment: Even if your answers are correct, your code has `O(n^2)` complexity.  That is almost always a disqualifier for these online judge sites.

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcKenzie For you suggestion. Can you suggest me that how to reduce/ By which method to reduce the complexity of this program.

Comment: @user216112, for starters, `i/j` is zero when `j > i`. Hence, the inner loop can be `for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j )`.

Comment: Further optimization: There will `N-1` times  that `i/j` is equal to `1`. Hence, you can use `for ( j = 1; j < i; ++j )` and add `N - 1` to the answer.

Comment: Find the sum in the first row and then multiply by row*(row+1)/2-1, where row is the number of rows

Comment: I have edited the question with some Sample Output , still I am not able to achieve the required result. Please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `int(i/j)` does not change much for larger values of `j`

i.e. if `j = 1000` `int(i/j)` will be `0` for `1-1000`, then it will be `1` for `1000-2000`, and so on. Using this fact, you can create an algorithm with much lower complexity.

e.g. if `N = 50000`, then for `j = 1000`, you will get `0... (1000)` times + `1 ..(1000)` times + `2..(1000)` times.... upto `49,000/1000... (1000)` times.

i.e. `div = N/j`  `ans += (div *(div-1) *j)`

You also need to make a correction if `N/j` is not a whole number as shown in the code below.

```
long long solve(long long N){
    long long ans = 0;
    long long div, mod;
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        div = N/i;
        mod = i- N%i;
        ans += (div * (div+1) * i)/2;

        // For the case when N does not go directly into i,
        // e.g. N = 47500, i = 1000, the last 500 need to be removed from the sum
        ans -= (mod-1) * div;
        printf ("\n i = %d, ans = %lld",i,ans);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

This is O(n) complexity.

Edit: Corrected to fix expected results.

Comment: That looks like good optimization by getting rid of unnecessary operations and nested loop

Comment: The compiler is not acceping the Program as working. As per the System If the Input is 2 2 4 Expected Correct Output should be 4 17

Comment: @user216112 The basic idea is to flatten the matrix to one dimension and find a formula to compute the sum.  You know what the sample data is and what the site claims is the correct answer.  The question is designed so that you can see patterns, and not naively write a nested loop.

Comment: The above function when providing input N=2 resulting in Sum =2 instead of 4.

Comment: @RishiKesh, Can you Help me crack these o(n^2) problem into 0(n), I just need to know how did you approach the problem. If there are any reference , please give me. I wanted to study in details about it. Thanks in adavance.

Comment: @user216112 It helps to think of the problem in terms of 1000's of numbers. What operation are we doing on a repeated basis. It also helps to map out the problem and expected answers in excel, which helps in the derivation of the formula.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention on `for`-loop condition

```
for i=1 to N-1  // in pseudo code
```

should be

```
for(int i=1;i < N;i++)
```

or

```
for(int i=1;i <= N-1;i++)
```

But NOT `for(int i=1;i < N-1;i++)` (that option loses the last item).

Next, expressions like `i/j` with integers are **integer division** that has only  integer part of result (without rounding). This will lead to `0` value if `i < j`.

And the last one, summarizing expression should be (from `sum += Matrix[i][j]`) as

```
ans += Matrix[i][j];
```

BUT where is your matrix?

**UPDATE**

If for same reasons, you use expression `N*i/j` instead of values from matrix (`Matrix[i][j]`), and you defensively want to use **integer arithmetic** you can minimize the code as:

```cpp
long long solve(long long N){
    long long ans = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < N; j++)
        {
            ans += N * i / j;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

at the same time you should understand that `long long` cannot save you from arithmetic overflow when `N > 1000000`

**UPDATE 2:**

Check the task about `1 ≤ i, j ≤ N` and if it is really <= N try changes for both `for` as

```
   for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
             ans += i / j;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Matrix Take the input from Input box, In site they have options to do that.

Comment: I could not find the difference, ans += N * i / j is  int temp = N*i/j;
        ans = ans + temp;

Comment: If you need deferences - `int temp = N*i/j;` requires more `sizeof(int)` bytes

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking the same, , For  more clarity I had made splitted(wanted to ask question in stackflow) the same.

Comment: The compiler is not acceping the Program as working. As per the System If the Input is 2 2 4 Expected Correct Output should be 4 17

Comment: what do you mean? If compiler does not accept program, what is error message? If the out is wrong - it is not "compiler", it is solution can produce some different answer

Comment: As I said in the Question : That the question comes from HackerEarth Challenge, and they have inbuilt program to check the answer, over there the Result is showing Incorrect Program. As the system when provided  the Input is 2 2 4 Expected Correct Output should be 4 17, but is not coming.

Comment: You can check one of similar example from hackerEarth. Like : https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/roy-and-matrix-sum-1/

Comment: I have edited the question with some Sample Output , still I am not able to achieve the required result. Please help me.

Comment: I have For N = 2 , Printing 1 ,0 , 2, 1 and N=4 , Printing 1 0 0 0 , 2 1 0 0 , 3 1 1 1, 4 2 1 1 , Can we generate some general equation through which  O(n) complexity can achieved.

Comment: Just use `ans += i / j;` instead of  `ans += N * i / j;` - I looked at updated question and fount, that it was mistake in your initial source code

Answer (score 1):

From Complexity point of view:

`int x = int(i/j)`   means `x > 0` only when `i >= j`. So you can avoid many unnecessary additions and divisions.

That is, `if Matrix[i][j] = int(i/j); then Matrix[i][j] = 0; for (i < j)`

Therefore, the `for` loops should be:

```
for i=1 to N-1
    for j=1 to i
        sum += Matrix[i][j];
```

**UPDATE 1:** After OP upated the question with sample output, it seems that the `for loop` for `i` should run till `N`. Modified Code as follow:

```
for(i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
    for(j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
        sum += (int)(i/j);
```

Comment: I have edited the question with some Sample Output , still I am not able to achieve the required result. Please help me.

Comment: @user216112: have you modified the code as mentioned in post. 2 problems in your code. [1] for loops should till `N` and not till `< N-1`. [2] `int temp = N*i/j;` should be `int temp = i/j;`

Answer (score 1):

First column is `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...`.
Second column is `0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, ...`.
Third columns is `0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, ...`.

Then derive formula to calculate sum of column **without loop** in O(1) using arithmetic progression sum formula and accurately calculating what is at the beginning and the end of each column.
Then iterate over columns. This will give you O(n) solution which fits given constraints.

Comment: Thanks, Can you provide some General Equation , which will solve this.